# How to create a new object with parts of existing object that may have nested object

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, adobe-indesign

I need to mirror the structure of page items in an InDesign document in a javascript object. I need it to match the nesting of page items in groups, groups within groups, etc.

This needs to be extensive to work with any InDesign document that is being worked on.

I need a recursive function that will build my object adding the child frames of any groups it finds and groups within those child frames, etc.

calling the same function if I find a group.

I've tried functions that call themselves if they come across a group, but I get a stack error on large files, on smaller files I only get results that go two levels deep.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var page = doc.pages[0];

var article = {
    id: page.id,
    frames: new Array()
}

for(i=0;i<page.pageItems.length;i++){
    var po = page.pageItems[i];
    var frame_objs = new Array();
    var frame_obj = {id: page.pageItems[i].id};
    if(po.getElements()[0].constructor.name == "Group"){
        frame_obj.frames = getChildFrames(po.pageItems);
    }
    article.frames.push(frame_obj);
}

create_file("~/Desktop/", "article.json", article);


function getChildFrames(pi_children){
    var child_frame_objs = new Array();
    for(i=0;i<pi_children.length;i++){
        var child_obj = {id: pi_children[i].id};
        if(pi_children[i].constructor.name == "Group"){
            child_obj.frames = getChildFrames(pi_children[i].pageItems);
        }
        child_frame_objs.push(child_obj);
    }
    return child_frame_objs;
}
```

The idea is to create a object something like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    components: [
        {
            type: "TextFrame",
            id: 201,
        }
        {
            type: "Group",
            id: 203,
            childFrames: [
                {
                    type: "Rectangle",
                    id: 1102
                },
                {
                    type: "Group",
                    id: 2034,
                    childFrames: [
                        {
                            type: "TextFrame",
                            id: 2345
                        },
                        {
                            type: "Group",
                            id: 99983,
                            childFrames: [
                                etc...
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I expect to get a properly simplified version of the page frames structure. As deeply nested as the layout is.

Can someone help me understand how to do this?

Comment: A better SO question includes a coding attempt, a description of the how that attempt's output doesn't match expectations, and a theory or two about what's gone wrong.  (And after all that, the input from which the output is to be produced).

Comment: Please post something that describes input your code handles and the output it actually produces.  Recursion (functions calling themselves) is almost certainly the most concise way to solve this.  If your recursive solution generated a stack error it's apt to be a coding mistake (unless the input has tens of thousands of levels of nesting).

Comment: I looked at your other questions asked on this site.  The collectionView question doesn't contain enough code to answer, the other two have been given very plausible looking answers without feedback from you (like a "checkmark"). I think you'd find it worthwhile to learn how to use this site. Most importantly: ask complete questions (input, code, output, expected output, etc), and finish articles you've started.  Mark accepted answers as accepted, add your own answer, etc.